# cant figure out what is wrong with code

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I am supposed to display the numbers 1 through 20 but I can not figure out what's wrong. At the beginning it is going correct but it is going to 21 instead of 20.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
TITLE 1through20
.data
.code

main proc

sub eax, eax
mov eax, 1
call writeDec
call crlf
mov ecx, 20

L1:
add eax, 1
call writeDec
call crlf
loop L1
exit

main EndP

END main
```

Comment: you're doing `20,19,....,3,2,1,0`. try `mov ecx, 19` instead.

Comment: Note: the `sub eax,eax` before `mov eax,1` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a separate display of the first number followed by a loop that displays 20 numbers. So in total you display 21 numbers which is 1 too many!
Simply drop 3 lines from your program (keep the `sub eax, eax` in this solution):

```
sub eax, eax
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;mov eax, 1
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;call writeDec
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;call crlf
mov ecx, 20

L1:
add eax, 1
call writeDec
call crlf
loop L1
```